# OpenVZ Premade Templates with Console Enabled

Tags: openvz, proxmox

So, I am setting up a new VPS host using OpenVZ. I am currently using hostbill as a billing system. Every-time I go to view the console of the VM it has created, it shows just a black input, allows be to type, but does not echo to the server or from the server. I have read that this is because they disable the OpenVZ templates Consoles by default. I have tried to follow a guide to enable the consoles on them, but only a few of the OS's succeeded. If anyone could provide me a location where I can download these templated and that have the console enabled by default, that would be great. I am attempting to use the x64 templates from the OpenVZ website under the column "Precreated templates".
https://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to create your own template from a running vm that's configured the way you want.

The steps to create an openvz template from a running ovz container:

```
vzctl stop [vps id]
```

Create /tmp/vz-template-exclude.txt and add these lines to it:

```
.bash_history
lost+found
/dev/*
/mnt/*
/tmp/*
/proc/*
/sys/*
/usr/src/*

tar –numeric-owner -czvf /vz/template/cache/template-name.tar.gz -X /tmp/vz-template-exclude.txt /vz/private/[vps id]
cp /etc/vz/dists/centos.conf /etc/vz/dists/template-name.conf
vzctl start [vps id]
```

That should do it!